# how to query the real json format from aws cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

when I run `aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids "XXX" --query "Subnets[*].Tags" --output json` I got this format:

```
[
  [
    {
        "Key": "k1",
        "Value": "v1"
    },
    {
        "Key": "k2",
        "Value": "v2"
    }
  ]
]
```

How can I get the real json format which only has {} not []. or at least not have two sets of []? I am using linux command.

Comment: You are asking the AWS CLI to display a subset of the JSON. The square brackets indicate that there is a _list_ of values. I suspect that the first square brackets is indicating a _list_ of `Subnets` and the second square brackets are indicating a _list_ of Tags. You could eliminate the Subnets brackets by specifying a particular subnet rather than using `Subnets[*]` -- for example, use `Subnets[0]` to specify the _first_ Subnet.

Comment: You current output is a **valid** json. If you require different form, that its your application at fault since it does not work with real json strings.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein works if I use Subnet[0]. Thanks

Comment: @Marcin if I do `aws ec2 describe-subnets XXX --query "Subnets[*].Tags" --output json > subnet_tags.json; aws ec2 create-tags XXX --tags file://subnet_tags.json` it shows error

Comment: `create-tags` requires subnet info in a different form. You have to manually (i.e. write program) to modify between the two forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON object of the form

```
[
  [
    {
        "Key": "k1",
        "Value": "v1"
    },
    {
        "Key": "k2",
        "Value": "v2"
    }
  ]
]
```

and you want to extract the inner array, you could use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

- `first` to get the first element of the array
- or `map(.[])` to get all nested arrays as top level array; or you could also simply use `flatten(1)`
- If you want to get a stream of inner arrays, `.[]` would help; and if you require a stream of all inner objects (on the second level), then `.[][]` does the job

Please note that a stream of objects is not valid JSON by itself, i.e. `{}{}` (a stream of two objects) is not valid JSON; `[{},{}]` (an array with two items, both objects) is valid JSON.